# Temporary variable increment

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to increment a metavariable, `%%x`, in a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) loop.

I'm not very familiar with Windows NT batch script commands, I tried to Google but nothing seemed to work, so that's why I'm asking.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
@echo off
for /l %%x in (6, 1, 32) do (
    echo %%x
    echo %%x+1
)
```

So, I want `%%x+1` to echo `7` when `%%x` is `6`. All it does is echo `6+1`.

Is something like that possible? In programming languages it's usually done this way, but I couldn't find out how to do it here.

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window, enter `set /?` and take a look at `Set /A`. You will probably need to use delayed expansion too, i.e. `SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion`. _However, I'm unsure why you couldn't just adjust it to `(7, 1, 33)` instead!_

Comment: @Compo I wanna use both values in a single loop, that's why I can't just adjust the loop values.

Comment: Follow my non italicised advice then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code might do what you want :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%x in (6, 1, 32) do (
    echo %%x
    set /a res=%%x+1
    echo !res!
)
```